# What is the fight meter for?

Tags: angry-birds-fight

After playing matches, in addition to experience and mission progress, there's a meter to the bottom right labelled "Fight!" that also goes up.

[image: screenshot]

What is this used for? So far, nothing else in the game uses this meter.

Answer (score 1):

It's some kind of ranking. For each fight you win or loose you'll gain ranking points. In this case 50. You can see your ranking and ranking points in the title screen in the right bottom corner (fight statistics).